I couldn't choose a specific option with Selenium in Python
I am trying to select the option "Yazar" in this  tag with Selenium and Python. However, I couldn't click this and choose the option "Yazar". How to do that?
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 form-group has-feedback">
   <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control required">
      <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle bs-placeholder btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="frmAkademiUnvan" title="Lütfen Seçiniz">
      <span class="filter-option pull-left">Lütfen Seçiniz</span>&nbsp;<span class="bs-caret">
      <span class="caret">
      </span>
      </span>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu open" role="combobox">
         <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false">
            <li data-original-index="1">
               <a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
               <span class="text">Yazar</span>
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark">
               </span>
               </a>
            </li>
            <li data-original-index="2">
               <a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
               <span class="text">Senior Author</span>
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark">
               </span>
               </a>
            </li>
            <li data-original-index="3">
               <a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
               <span class="text">Corresponding Author</span>
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark">
               </span>
               </a>
            </li>
            <li data-original-index="4">
               <a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
               <span class="text">Eşit Katkılı Yazar</span>
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark">
               </span>
               </a>
            </li>
            <li data-original-index="5">
               <a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
               <span class="text">Lisansüstü Öğrenci</span>
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark">
               </span>
               </a>
            </li>
            <li data-original-index="6">
               <a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
               <span class="text">İkinci Danışman Yazar</span>
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark">
               </span>
               </a>
            </li>
            <li data-original-index="7">
               <a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
               <span class="text">Tebliği Sunan</span>
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark">
               </span>
               </a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <select id="frmAkademiUnvan" name="yazarTur" title="Lütfen Seçiniz" data-live-search="false" class="selectpicker form-control required" required="true" tabindex="-98">
         <option class="bs-title-option" value="">Lütfen Seçiniz</option>
         <option value="1">Yazar</option>
         <option value="2">Senior Author</option>
         <option value="3">Corresponding Author</option>
         <option value="4">Eşit Katkılı Yazar</option>
         <option value="5">Lisansüstü Öğrenci</option>
         <option value="6">İkinci Danışman Yazar</option>
         <option value="7">Tebliği Sunan</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>

I am sharing the related Python code. I run this code to choose the specific option. However, it's not choosing the "Yazar" option:
# 15) Choose author type with WebDriverWait
            lutfen_seciniz_span = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'filter-option') and contains(text(), 'Lütfen Seçiniz')]"))
            )
            lutfen_seciniz_span.click()
            
# Click on "Yazar"
yazar_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@role='option' and .//span[text()='Yazar']]"))
            )
yazar_option.click()

I don't get any error messages. Terminal returns empty space.

Try posting the actual python code.

Can you share your code trials and error from your console? Also share the URL of the site if it is public?

I edited and included the Python code. The site is not public. It requires to login to reach this site.

You need to use Selenium's Select Class to handle dropdowns/select list elements.
Refer the code below:
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
select_node = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "frmAkademiUnvan"))))
select_node.select_by_visible_text("Yazar")

Imports:
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

